# MySQL NOW() saving time as 00:00:00 in some cases

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

I have an interesting problem on a commercial site I maintain where some users are not receiving confirmation of their purchases, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why. The only thing I notice about most of these cases is that the time their subscription is saved in the database is set to `00:00:00`.

The query that saves subscription info to the database is MySQL's [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function, so it gets saved in a `datetime` column with a format like this: `2016-02-10 04:34:12`. But in many cases, the time is being saved with 0's for the time, so something like this: `2016-02-10 00:00:00`. It's hard for me to believe that so many users are saving subscriptions at midnight, especially since their payment time is often many hours afterwards.

Does anyone know of anything, maybe a MySQL bug or something, that might be causing the `NOW()` function to set the time to `00:00:00`? The current version of MySQL being used in this case is `5.0.95`.

I don't know if this is related to my problem with the confirmations, but it might shed a clue into what else might be causing a problem.

Comment: Are you sure that it is mysql's now() function which causes the issue and not other part of the code updates the field in question this way?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely what I thought at first, too. But I've searched the code thoroughly and can't find anywhere else that updates this value for any reason. If it's not caused by the MySQL function, I'll just have to keep searching for whatever could be causing it. I thought I'd ask though in case maybe someone else has run into a similar issue.

Comment: Is not it possible that you have some kind of transaction open or perhaps an sql script is running for a long time and the connection re-used? Now() by default returns the time when the statement execution started, not the actual time!

Comment: That's a good point I hadn't considered, but no, in this case it's not the issue. It turns out a separate app that connects to the same database causes the problem, so the NOW() function is working exactly as one would expect. I'll have to look elsewhere to find the problem with the subscription confirmations. Thanks, though!